# Unity, Visual Effect Graph - How can I make a 'Trailing Particle' effect?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Using the Visual Effect Graph (in Unity) I would like to make a trailing particle effect, like in the [Visual Effect Graph demo video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYRoa.jpg).

[image: image](i.imgur.com/4Qib9In.mp4[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCNGw.png))

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TrailRenderer in unity. TrailRenderer is an Unity inbuilt component. By using that you can custom your line width and height of that renderer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that it needs to be done with the Visual Effect Graph.